# How to copy blobs in Azure Storage using PowerShell without override and without confirmation for each file?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script using Azure PowerShell modules to back-up Blob Service container to another, backup Storage Account container.

Because of the size of the container (several TB), I want the backup to be incremental, so I want to never override files in the destination container (this is sufficient for us because we never update existing files in the source container).

However, I can't find any way to make the script behave like this (not to override files in destination container) *without being asked to confirm/decline every potential override*. I want this confirmation to be suppressed.

Example:

```
$sourceContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $sourceStorageAccountKey
$destinationContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $DestinationStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $destinationStorageAccountKey 

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $sourceContext -Container $SourceContainerName

# Asks for confirmation for every blob that already exists in the destination container
$blobs | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destinationContext -DestContainer $DestinationContainerName
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try using the `-Force` parameter.

From the [`documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603695.aspx):

> -Force
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet overwrites the destination blob without
>   prompting you for confirmation.

So your command would be:

```
$blobs | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destinationContext -DestContainer $DestinationContainerName -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

According the command help document [Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603695.aspx) ,maybe It has no way to not overwrite the existing files with parameter without asking. Since the backup container size is several TB, excluding the existing files(blob) via PowerShell code maybe not a good choice.

Please have a try to with **-confirm: $true** it will be asked just once if you select [Yes to All] or [No to All]. As  you don’t want to overwrite the existing files, please select the [No to All] option.

```
$blobs | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destinationContext -DestContainer $DestinationContainerName -Confirm:$true
```

[image: Confirm]

By the way -Force it will **overwrite** all existing files without asking.